# How to Deploy a Rails 3 Website

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment

I am ready to deploy my rails 3 site to a server. Who would be the best provider to go with? I need it to be easy to deploy and low cost. Does anyone have any experiences they can share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://railsplayground.com is cheapest, they are charging $5/month

heroku.com is free for subdomain hosting ie., http://example.heroku.com

the above two are only for testing purpose if your are going live deployment then

either choose AmazonEc2 or rackspace.com/cloud/

regards,
senthilK

Comment: Thanks, and yes at this stage i only wanted to put something out there for testing.

Answer (score 2):

http://railsplayground.com/

I did it with my first 2 applictions, they have low cost service and online 24 hours support, they send by mail all the credentials to acces your vps or whatever service you have. But if you are new at deploying they can offer to place the app for you, you just send the app by ticket to them and they'll do it.

I have a VPS at railsplayground now, and I pay about 35usd/month, but I have 2 apps on this server and I can have more.. as much as the server can take it, when it reaches the limit, you can upgrade it.

http://www.heroku.com/  is much easier to use, but if you have an app that do uploads on server, heroku will not do it. they store only application.

I am pleased with railsplayground for now.

Comment: did not know that about Heroku, my site will involve uploading documents to the site

Comment: well, yes, I also deployed my app to Heroku first, but then I had to move it out, cause the client want it to store uploads on the same server.